# Can't get value of select list with Javascript when it is created using PHP array from database

Tags: javascript, php, select

If I generate a select list using PHP from the results of a database query, for some reason I can't then use Javascript to get the value of the currently selected item. I tested this code with a static list and it works no problem. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY name ASC"; 
    try
    {
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE); //each column is addressed by the primary key
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $("#animal_list").change(function(){
                 var animalValue = $(this).val(); 
                 window.location.href="animal_list.php?id=" + animalValue;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="animal_list" name="animal_list">
        <?php
            foreach($results as $res)
            {
        ?>
            <?php echo '<option value="'. $res['id'] . '">' ?>
                <?php echo $res['name']  ?>
            </option>

        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            echo '<input type="text" id="npsw_code" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" readonly>';
        }
        else
            echo '<input type="text" id="npsw_code" value="" readonly>';
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Testing with a static list works. Here is the example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $("#fruits").change(function(){
                 var fruitValue = $(this).val(); 
                 window.location.href="fruits.php?id=" + fruitValue;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Fruits
    <select id="fruits" name="fruits">
        <option value="0">Apple</option>
        <option value="1">Pear</option>
        <option value="2">Watermelon</option>
        <option value="3">Orange</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            echo 'My Fruit <input type="text" id="myfruit" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" readonly>';
        }
        else
            echo 'My Fruit <input type="text" id="myfruit" value="" readonly>';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the browser source? Right click the window and view source.

Comment: `listChange` is not defined

Comment: Well first of all the way you mix PHP and HTML, leave much to be desired.  Secondly, view source and see what you select looks like.  It makes no difference where it came from.  For all we know it has no options.  It's just a likely that the query returned nothing as anything else.  Without the HTML that is output it's just speculation on what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind it was a typo. The column in my database was 'code' not 'id'. So it should have read  . Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

remove `onchange="listChange()"` because is not defined and we dont need it.

and use `$(this).find('option:selected').val();` for get value of option selected.

```
$("#animal_list").change(function(){
    var animalValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val(); 
    window.location.href="animal_list.php?id=" + animalValue;
});
```

Comment: Only need `$(this).val()` Lê Phi

Comment: Magearlik: please copy screenshot in view-source.

Answer (score 0):

First off I would clean this mess up.

```
<select id="animal_list" name="animal_list">
    <?php
        foreach($results as $res)
        {
    ?>
        <?php echo '<option value="'. $res['id'] . '">' ?>
            <?php echo $res['name']  ?> <!-- missing ; -->
        </option>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        echo '<input type="text" id="npsw_code" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" readonly>';
    }
    else
        echo '<input type="text" id="npsw_code" value="" readonly>';
?>
```

Sorry I just can't deal with poorly formatted code, it makes reading it a chore.  It just seems like so much wasted effort.

```
<select id="animal_list" name="animal_list">
    <?php foreach($results as $res): ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $res['id'];?>"><?php echo $res['name'];  ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<?php
    $readonly = '';
    $npsw_code = '';

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $readonly = ' readonly';
        $npsw_code = $_GET['id'];
    }
?>

<input type="text" id="npsw_code" value="<?php echo $npsw_code; ?>" <?php echo $readonly; ?>>
```

We'll also ignore this (missing ; ):

```
  <?php echo $res['name']  ?>
```

Probably a syntax error, but see that's what happens when you cant read the code.

Javascript don't care how the HTML got in the page, only what the HTML looks like.  Without knowing what it looks like, all we can do is guess.  You can view source and see what it looks like.

Otherwise, put an alert in the on change handler and see what it says.

```
   $("#animal_list").change(function(){
       var animalValue = $(this).val(); 
       alert(animalValue);
       window.location.href="animal_list.php?id=" + animalValue;
   });
```

Alert has the nice side effect of halting/pausing Javascript execution so it will interrupt the page redirect.  This will tell you 2 things,

1. your event is being fired on change
2. the value is correct.

Comment: Ok I tidied it up. However I still get an empty value in the alert.

Comment: Is the JavaScript executing before the HTML prints the list?? PHP should execute before JavaScript anyway right?

Comment: Why does the static version work, yet dynamically getting the list from the database does not????

Comment: How should I know, look at the source code (right click > view source) and see what the actual html output from the server looks like.  For all we know your database has an error or returns an empty dataset.  Which means the select could be all messed up.

Comment: Maybe you have that ID used somewhere else, ID's have to be unique.  PHP always runs before javascript, and with `onReady` the JS should wait on the DOM to populate.

Comment: When I run the code the select is not empty. PHP gets the info from the database and I can iterate the list of items and they print OK. The problem is using Javascript to get the value of the currently selected item. If you write a select list by hand ie you don't gets its values from a  PHP database array it works.

Comment: Look at the fruits example.